# How to dispose CrossMediaManager properly?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm playing an HLS content on CrossMediaManager. When users press back, I'm trying to dispose the player, but the player is still playing, I can see it's running on notification drawer and I can listen to video. Here is the code I've tried.

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    CrossMediaManager.Current.Dispose();
    VideoPlayer.Dispose();
}
```

VideoPlayer is the Reference name of the VideoView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put following code in your navigated page. When you back to mainpage, this plugin will be closed.

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            var player = CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaPlayer;
             player.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]